# How to reference a date range from another CTE in a where clause without joining to it?

Tags: date, hive, hiveql, common-table-expression, where-clause

I'm trying to write a query for Hive that uses the system date to determine both yesterday's date as well as the date 30 days ago. This will provide me with a rolling 30 days without the need to manually feed the date range to the query every time I run it.

I have that code working fine in a CTE. The problem I'm having is in referencing those dates in another CTE without joining the CTEs together, which I can't do since there's not a common field to join on.

I've tried various approaches but I get a "ParseException" every time.

```
WITH
date_range AS (
SELECT
CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-30*60*60*24,'yyyyMMdd') AS INT) AS start_date,
CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyyMMdd') AS INT) AS end_date
)
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE date_id BETWEEN (SELECT start_date FROM date_range) AND (SELECT end_date FROM date_range)
```

The intended result is the set of records from myTable that have a date_id between the start_date and end_date as found in the CTE date_range. Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a cross join, it does not require ON condition. Your date_range dataset is one row only, you can CROSS JOIN it with your_table if necessary and it will be transformed to a map-join (your small dataset will be broadcasted to all the mappers and loaded into each mapper memory and will work very fast), check the `EXPLAIN` command and make sure it is a map-join:

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize=250000000;

WITH
date_range AS (
SELECT
CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-30*60*60*24,'yyyyMMdd') AS INT) AS start_date,
CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyyMMdd') AS INT) AS end_date
)

SELECT t.* 
  FROM myTable t
CROSS JOIN date_range d
WHERE t.date_id BETWEEN d.start_date AND d.end_date
```

Also instead if this you can calculate dates in the where clause:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM myTable t
CROSS JOIN date_range d
WHERE t.date_id 
      BETWEEN CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-30*60*60*24,'yyyyMMdd') AS INT) 
          AND CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyyMMdd') AS INT)
```

Comment: I will try this, thanks! I know I can calculate dates in the where clause, but I have dates being referenced throughout the query (including places other than the where clause), so I was hoping I could define the dates once and reuse them by referencing them.